# React-new-window, how to position pop up windows?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

[Original Web-page with no pop up menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUxhu.png)

[Web-page after adding pop up menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYeHw.png)

Hello, I am working on building a web page that shows statistics to a user depending on what option they chose. instead of having the components glued in one position I am using react-new-window to open them up in pop up menus which will allow the user to move it to a different location on the screen if they wish to do so.

My problem is that when I open up the application all of my pop up boxes are on the left hand side of the screen. How can I get them into the original positions that they were in before I started using react-new-window? Thank you!

Comment: Hi, is there a way you can share your code? 
It seems based on the [github repo](https://github.com/rmariuzzo/react-new-window#features) that the component has a prop `center` and the default value is `parent` so maybe you can wrap the component with the same html elements you had before?
e.g.
```
const Demo = () => (
  <div>
  <NewWindow >
    <h1>Hi </h1>
  </NewWindow>
  </div>
)
```
Also the docs is saying you can pass `features` props which you can control the window features. [look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features)